# Sinatra and Markaby: "Template Engine Not Found"

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Using the standard gem for using Markaby with Sinatra, listed at http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions-wild.html

sudo gem install markaby

Password:

Successfully installed builder-2.1.2

Successfully installed markaby-0.5

2 gems installed

sudo gem install sbfaulkner-sinatra-markaby -s http://gems.github.com

Password:

Successfully installed sbfaulkner-sinatra-markaby-0.9.2.2

1 gem installed

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/markaby'

get '/' do
  markaby :template
end
```

RuntimeError at /

Template engine not found: mab

Comment: I followed your instructions and it works fine for me. What version of Sinatra do you have?

Comment: It's not a Sinatra problem since sinatra knows what the "markaby" function means, which comes out of Sinatra-Markaby.  So the problem is either in Markaby or Sinantra-Markaby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Sinatra is now using tilt.

Markaby, at least as of version 0.6.10 provides a Tilt module.  Have you tried updating to the latest markaby and adding:

```
require 'markaby/tilt'
```